# Pedicting from a conv2d model says the image must be 4d too

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

This is the model I've created:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), input_shape = (28, 28, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
# added layers
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=256, epochs=25, validation_split=0.3)
```

But loading an image for prediction as such:

```
test_image = np.array(img)
test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
test_image /= 255
# image.shape is 28, 28, 3
print((model.predict(test_image)))
```

results in the following error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_11 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 28, 3)

X.shape is (2163, 28, 28, 3) where 2163 is the number of pictures of 28x28 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a batch dimension, because Keras is used to that input shape. I suggest you use `np.expand_dims`:

```
test_image = np.array(img).astype('float32')
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)/255
test_image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(test_image, 28, 28)

print((model.predict(test_image)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The model expects an input with 4 dimensions. This means that you have to reshape your image with .reshape(n_images, 28, 28,3 ). Now you have added an extra dimension without changing the data . Basically, you need to reshape your data to (n_images, x_shape, y_shape, channels). Try it, Make sure the shape of your input layer is 28,28,3

Comment: Tried that, I still get the same error: Input 0 of layer sequential_11 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 28, 3)

Comment: you need to reshape your data to (n_images, x_shape, y_shape, channels).

Comment: Reshaping my data would mean changing the X.shape and y.shape right? Reshaping my image to (n_images, 28, 28,3 ) results in: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (n_images,28,28,3)

Comment: you have one image so if you reshape to 1,28,28,3 that should work

Comment: What is the shape of your input layer

Comment: Shape of my input layer is (28, 28, 3) [input_shape = X.shape[1:]] which I've just realized.  The program runs fine, but shouldn't it be 4d?

Comment: Channel_last reshape :
X.reshape(list(X.shape) + [1])    # (2163, 28, 28, 3)
Channel first reshape:
X = X.reshape([X.shape[0], [1]] + list(X.shape[1:]))    # (2163, 3, 28, 28)

Comment: try to explicitly put your input shape to 2163,28,28,3, in model shape should be None,28,28,3